# How to check if node is empty

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to make a variable, which tells me, whether node1 has something in it or not. node1 can be an empty element  or it may contain an attribute. But right now I would like to know how achieve answer "false" when the node1 is empty .

```
<xsl:variable name="elementHasData">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="node1 != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether `node1` contains text or other child nodes:

```
<xsl:variable name="elementHasData" select="node1/node()" />
```

Check whether `node1` contains child nodes or attributes:

```
<xsl:variable name="elementHasData" select="node1/node() or node1/@*" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:variable name="elementHasData">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space(node1)) gt 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: That 8-line `xsl:choose` is unnecessary and also makes it so that `$elementHasData` is a node fragment instead of a boolean. You should  just do: `<xsl:variable name="elementHasData" select="boolean(normalize-space(node1))" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in **XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:variable name="elementHasData" select="if (node1[node()]) then 'true()' else 'false()'"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check either any node or any attribute then you can go to this.

```
<xsl:variable name="elementHasData" select="if (node1[@* | node()]) then 'true()' else 'false()'"/>
```